# Wordpress search three different forms

Tags: wordpress, search, custom-post-type

I have three different search forms in a page. Products, Restaurants and Pages are different post types. Tried showing result in search.php by hidden input type. Its not showing the result as i expected. Something in my code is wrong. Kindly advice or suggest.

form 1

```
<form role="search" method="get"  action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="hidden" value="Restaurant" name="post_type" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

form 2

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="hidden" value="Products" name="post_type" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

form 3

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
                        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="Pages" />
                    </form>
```

following is my search.php structure

```
$myvalue = $_GET['post_type'];

        if ($myvalue == "Restaurant"){
            echo "res";

            function SearchFilter($query) {
                if ($query->is_search) {
                    $query->set('post_type', 'sanha-restau');
                }
                return $query;
            }

            add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');

        if ( have_posts() ) :
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                echo '<ul><li><strong>';
                echo get_the_title()  . '</strong><br> (';
                echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 200) . ') ';
                echo '</li></ul>';              
            endwhile;
            else :
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
        endif;


        } else if ($myvalue == "Products"){
            echo "pro";

            function SearchFilter($query) {
                if ($query->is_search) {
                    $query->set('post_type', 'sanha-product');
                }
                return $query;
            }

            add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');

        if ( have_posts() ) :
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                echo '<ul><li><strong>';
                echo get_the_title()  . '</strong><br> (';
                echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 200) . ') ';
                echo '</li></ul>';              
            endwhile;
            else :
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
        endif;


        } else if ($myvalue == "Pages"){
            echo "pages";

            if ( have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    echo '<ul><li><strong>';
                    echo get_the_title()  . '</strong><br> (';
                    echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 200) . ') ';
                    echo '</li></ul>';              
                endwhile;
                else :
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
            endif;

        }
```

please advice. thanks

Comment: Please provide your feedback if you found answer was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

By checking your code it seems you would like to search in 3 post types

**`Products, Restaurants and Pages`**

As per docs you can use array for `post_type` to search in multiple post type.

where `s` parameter in [**`WP_QUERY`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
Show posts based on a keyword search.

s (string) - Search keyword.
Show Posts based on a keyword search

Display posts that match the search term "abc":
```

**Note : I have use `abc` to search**  you can change it to `esc_sql($_REQUEST['s'])`

```
$searchQuery = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('products', 'restaurants','page'),
    's' => 'abc' // <<-- change this to make it work --> esc_sql($_REQUEST['s'])
));

if ($searchQuery->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $searchQuery->have_posts() ) : $searchQuery->the_post();
        echo '<ul><li><strong>';
        echo get_the_title()  . '</strong><br> (';
        echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 200) . ') ';
        echo '</li></ul>';              
    endwhile;
    else :
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
endif;
```

So there will be one query for search and no need to use `add_filter`.
Above `WP_Query` will search your keyword in 3 post types.

Answer (score 0):

```
function load_custom_search_template(){
    if(isset($_REQUEST['custom_search'])){
        require('search.php');
        die();
    }
}
add_action('init','load_custom_search_template');
```

this code worked with all

and following code for search.php

```
$myquery = '';
function searchfilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
        if(isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
            $type = $_GET['post_type'];
                if($type == 'sanha-product') {
                    $query->set('post_type',array('sanha_product'));
                    $myquery = 'Products Found For : ';
                }
                elseif($type == 'sanha-restau'){
                    $query->set('post_type',array('sanha_restau'));
                    $myquery = 'Resaurants Found For : ';
                }
                elseif($type == 'pages'){
                    $query->set('post_type',array('pages'));
                    $myquery = 'Search Result For : ';
                }
        }       
    }
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```